# avoid passing explicit id to create a post using prisma

Tags: postgresql, psql, prisma

I've got a prisma schema:

````
model post {
  post_id                                   String         @id @default(dbgenerated()) @db.Uuid
  content                                   String?
  vote_count                                Int?           @default(0)
  is_reported                               Boolean        @default(false)
  is_deleted                                Boolean        @default(false)
  
  created_date                              DateTime       @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updated_date                              DateTime       @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  title                                     String         @db.VarChar(300)
  created_by                                String         @db.Uuid
  last_updated_by                           String         @db.Uuid
  author                                    plug_user      @relation("author_posts_rel", fields: [created_by], references: [user_id])
  contributor                               plug_user[]    @relation("contributors_posts_rel")
  post_reply                                post_reply[]
  tags                                      tag[]
}``` 
   
where prisma generates the type for post as:   
  
scalars: $Extensions.GetResult<{
    post_id: string
    content: string | null
    vote_count: number | null
    is_reported: boolean
    is_deleted: boolean
    created_date: Date
    updated_date: Date
    title: string
    created_by: string
    last_updated_by: string
  }, ExtArgs["result"]["post"]>
````

whenever I'd like to save a post, I have to either explicitly pass in a `post_id` or pass undefined as:

`prisma.post.create({data: {...payload, post_id: undefined, ...}})`

but, since this is something that the db should generate itself, I'd like to avoid doing this, is there a way to do that?

Comment: What happens when you pass in `undefined`? Does the database generate an ID for you?

Comment: @SebDieBln , yes it actually does, but it could be optional, it is only restricted by the types required by prisma model